# how to avoid multi prometheus instances remote write

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

i wanna set up prometheus ha in production environment.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For long storage this type of structure is build. The solution is you can send your samples from prometheus to other clustered storage system. Remote
write sends samples as they are ingested to another system. Remote read allows
PromQL to transparently use samples from another system, as if it were stored
locally within the Prometheus. 
For this you can edit your **prometheus.yml** and write those rules.

```
remote_write:
    - url: http://localhost:1234/write
remote_read:
    - url: http://localhost:1234/read
```

You have to enable **write_relabel_configs** flag for the service.